# Negative Lookahead with variable length main match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to generate a regex script that matches a single date if not followed by a ',', 'and' or '&'. For example in I would want to match

```
on mondays
```

or

```
on monday
```

but not

```
on mondays,
```

or

```
on mondays and
```

or

```
on mondays &
```

So far I have:

```
\b(?:on|in)\s+(?:weeknights?|weekends?|weekdays?|mornings?|afternoons?|nights?|evenings?|mondays?|tuesdays|wednesdays?|thursdays?|fridays?|saturdays?|sundays?|(?:(?:mon|tues?|weds?|thu(?:rs|r)?|fri|sat|sun)s?\.?))(?!(?:\,|\s+and\s+|\s+&\s+))
```

but in the case of

```
on mondays,
```

it just matches

```
on monday
```

instead of no matches at all. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a word break `\b` in there:

```
on mondays?\b(?!\s*(and|[&,]))
```

http://regex101.com/r/yW6fL4/1